# Gmail is throwing emails from my academic address to spam

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email, spam-prevention

Today I sent an email from my Google Apps academic address to a friend of mine, and he said that didn't received nothing.

Then I send an email to my personal Gmail and noticed that it send it to spam. Why Google marked my academic email as spam? How can I reverse that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail help shows the below instructions in how to handle this situation.

> Find a message wrongly classified as spam, you can unmark the message. Just select the message, and click the Not Spam button that appears at the top and bottom of your current view. Unmarking a message will automatically move it to your inbox.
>
> If you find that some senders' messages are consistently being mislabeled as spam, you can prevent this by:
>
> Adding their email addresses to your Contacts list. Gmail will deliver messages from members of your Contacts list to your inbox, unless we know with high confidence that they are spam.
>           Some messages sent from contacts which are very clearly spam can be sent directly to your Spam label. More importantly, in some cases messages from contacts will not be sent to Spam but will be marked with a red warning banner if the content is suspicious - for example, your friend's or contact's account has been compromised and used to send phishing messages.
>       Creating a filter so the messages are never sent to Spam.
>
> If you're sending to Gmail users and are seeing your messages marked as spam, please review our Bulk Senders guide.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en